# Problem creating localStorage key dynamically using template literals

Tags: javascript, local-storage, template-literals

I am trying to save values to localStorage with keys that are created using template literals to create new a new string from an existing string and a variable as the key, and concatenation a string and a number as the value.

In the console, the strings appear to be formatted correctly for local storage, but when run it produces the error "
TypeError: Failed to execute 'setItem' on 'Storage': 2 arguments required, but only 1 present."

*The snippet below throws a sandbox error rather than the one I receive in my local environment. Can anyone shed some light at what I'm doing wrong?[image]

```js
var tm="Charlotte Knights";
var cl ="AA";
var yr = 2019;

console.log(`"my${cl}", "${tm}_${yr}"`)
localStorage.setItem(`"my${cl}", "${tm}_${yr}"`)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`` localStorage.setItem(`"my${cl}", "${tm}_${yr}"`) `` passes **one** string to the `setItem` function. To pass two, you need to end the template literal prior to the comma, then start another after it:

```
localStorage.setItem(`my${cl}`, `${tm}_${yr}`)
// --------------------------^--^
```

Also get rid of the `"` within the templates, unless you want actual `"` characters in the key and value.

Comment: @NickParsons - Thanks! How did my eyes read right past that? (BTW: You can use three backticks on either side when you need to have backticks in the inline code block, which has the advantage of not having to escape the backtick.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder oh, thanks for the handy tip :) I was trying to escape them using "\" but that wasn't working ha ha